# Periodic Work Manger not executing when application is closed

Tags: android, react-native, backgroundworker, android-workmanager

I hade implemented Work manager to send messeage to server in the background as native code in react native but it is not working. kindly help me to solve this background work. Or let me know how to background tasks in best way in react native.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "10001" ;
    private final static String default_notification_channel_id = "default" ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Constraints constraints =new Constraints.Builder()
              .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)// there are some more constraints we can set
              .build();
    Log.d("dsfdsf","dsfsdfdsfdsfdsfdf");
    //create one time request
      Data inputData = new Data.Builder()
              .putString("WORKER", "app")
              .build();

      final PeriodicWorkRequest myWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(WorkService.class,1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
              .setInputData(inputData)
              .setConstraints(constraints)
              .build();
      WorkManager workManager =  WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
      workManager.enqueue(myWorkRequest);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more/specific details like what is not working in your case.

Comment: I want to send offline meessages to server when app is closed and connection is available